# What would the locus of a point be whose difference of distances from any two points is always equal to the distance between the points?

Tags: coordinate-systems, plane-geometry, locus

Let me give an example to explain my question more, what would the collection of possible points which satisfy the following condition look like? :

**the point's distance from  $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ is always equal to 4(which is the distance between $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ itself)?**

---

Well I was pretty sure it would be a pair of rays: one starting from (2,0) and extending infinitely towards the positive x-axis and the other starting from (-2,0) and extending infinitely to the negative x-axis. But when I tried plotting this on a graphing tool, I was surprised that it didn't give any locus.

Why does this happen? is it some personal error of mine while plotting the graph or is it something else?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equations directly, the solution seems to be $P=(x,0)$ for all $x$, i.e.  the locus would be the $x$ axis.

The algebra has to be corrected for sign ambiguity when squaring square roots. Therefore, the part of the axis with $-2\lt x\lt 2$ must be excluded.

Comment: I meant what would be the figure depicting all the set of such points be like? Would it be a hyperbola, pair of rays,....? That is, if we were to collectively show the variance of a variable point P(x,y) which follows the condition: $|PA-PB|=4$ then what would it look like? (A and B are the same points as shown in the figure I attached in my post)

Comment: ps: desmos is just a graphing tool... in the third equation(green) to the left... I input the equation which meets the situation I am mentioning... and was hoping to see a curve/figure but it just doesn't give any locus

Comment: I revised my answer.

Comment: yes, that's what my guess was... that it would be a pair of rays one starting from (2,0) and extending infinitely towards the positive x-axis and the other starting from (-2,0) and extending infinitely to the negative x-axis. I just didn't get why the graph tool didn't give any output for that

Comment: Your title needs clarification.  "distance from any two points" should be "difference of distances from any two points".  No comment on graph tool.

Comment: Yes. Have made the changes.